# I/O Not Working (Copy File, Paste It)

Tags: java, file-io

I'm trying to get this piece of code to work. It's a basic I/O system that copies one file and pastes it into the same directory with the chosen name. It should be simple but for some reason the program runs, it creates the second file but then it gets stuck. The CPU for Java process sits at around 5% and the file is never completed. It only copies over some of the data and then I'd imagine it's stuck in an infinite loop somewhere.

I've already compared my code with the Byte Streams tutorial on [the Oracle website](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/bytestreams.html).

EXTRA: I just asked it to output what it was reading and it's stuck on an infinite loop reading the value `255`. If that helps. Also, I compiled the code directly off the Oracle website and it does the same thing.

It appears consistent from what I can tell. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? Thank you.

(P.S: I'm Using Eclipse 4.2.0).

This is what I'm doing to copy the file:

```
package fileIO;

import java.io.*;

import system.Debug;

public class fileUtil {

    public static void copyFileTo(String file2Copy, String file2Paste) {
        FileInputStream fin = null;
        FileOutputStream fout = null;

        try {
            fin = new FileInputStream(file2Copy);
            fout = new FileOutputStream(file2Paste);

            int aByte;
            while ((aByte = fin.read()) != -1) {
                fout.write(aByte);
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            Debug.out("Error: File Not Found: " + file2Copy);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Debug.out("Error: File IO Exception Copying: " + file2Copy);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Debug.out("Error: General Exception Closing Streams:" + file2Copy);
        } finally {
            try {
                fin.close();
                fout.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Debug.out("Error: File IO Exception Closing Streams: " + file2Copy);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Debug.out("Error: General Exception Closing Streams:" + file2Copy);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In my program main class I run this:

```
fileUtil.copyFileTo("google.bmp", "google(1).bmp");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I found out what was happening. Was a really nooby mistake.

I'll put my pride aside encase anyone else has this problem. It's not an infinite loop, it's just that copying using ByteStreams takes AGES. I was expecting a fast result from small image files but even small image files take a long long time to copy. I let it run for 30 seconds and the program terminated properly and I got my image copy just fine.

Thank god it's solved, I was beginning to worry.

Answer (score 1):

Try to do `fout.flush()` before you close the OutputStream.

Comment: Didn't work sorry. No observable difference, I added it after fin.close()

Answer (score 0):

... or do not invent bother re-inventing the wheel: use [FileUtils.copyFile](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io//javadocs/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#copyFile) from the proven Apache commons-io which does it in one line.

(beware: this comment is not as innocent as it seems: `File.rename` does not work well on Windows shares - commons-io is *always* the safe bet to do these things)

**Edit**

1. Stackoverflow is not a goog place for "homework" - or you must at least say so. It is not that your problem is not real. It is that your objectives differ: you want to learn something, we want to make it work reliably with minimum maintenance.
2. ...which leads to my second point: when you are in professional life, never program this again. As you discovered, even if you make it work, it may be extremely inefficient, handle errors incorrectly, etc.. This is particularly true with IO which is **always** more tricky than it seems.
3. Finally, since I gave you a link to a well trusted library under Apache 2.0 license, maybe you could have had a look at the [source code](http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/commons-io/commons-io/2.1/commons-io-2.1-sources.jar!/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.java?format=ok) ?

Comment: As a University Computer Science student it's required of me to know the full process of file input and output. I'm not reinventing the wheel, I'm making sure I know how it works.

Comment: That's not what my question was. I didn't ask how to get this working with minimum maintenance or even to get it working reliably. I said, here's my code and it doesn't work. I'd like to know why.

Also, this isn't homework. You don't get homework at University. This is study, my study leads me to need to understand File I/O. Don't see a problem posting here at all.